# IOS Search as Table View Section Header

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a search bar as the table header, all works fine, except that it scrolls with the table.  So putting the search bar as a section header seems to work, except that it will loose the keyboard when scrolling and will not give it back by touching the search text in the bar.

Any solutions to this.  Seems like the section header has some limitations for text input?